# Existence of a generic extension in which a Suslin tree exists

Tags: set-theory, forcing

I'm reading Theorem 15.23 of Jech's *Set Theory*, where it is proved that there exists a generic extension in which there exists a Suslin tree.

The notion of forcing $(P,<)$ is the set of all countable normal trees, ordered by reverse inclusion. Let $G$ be generic, and define $\mathcal T=\bigcup G$ in $V[G]$, the author claims that $\mathcal T$ is a Suslin tree in $V[G]$. It is not hard to prove in $V[G]$ that $\mathcal T$ is a normal tree of height $\omega_1$ , and that $V[G]$ preserves cardinals, so we need only to show that $\mathcal T$ has only countable antichains in $V[G]$.

I have read the proof of this, however there is something I don't understand:

Let $\dot A$ be a name for a maximal antichain $A$ of $\mathcal T$. Let $T$ be a condition such that $T\Vdash(\dot{A}$ is a maximal antichain of $\mathcal T$). Let $T_0\leq T$ be arbitraty, then $T_0\Vdash(\dot A$ is a maximal antichain in $\mathcal T$ and $\mathcal T$ is an extension of $T_0$); I constructed a name $\dot{\mathcal T}$ for $\mathcal T$ and proved that $||T_0\subseteq\dot{\mathcal T}||=T_0$, and as $T_0$ forces that $\mathcal T$ is a normal tree and $|| T_0$ is a normal tree$||=1$; this is a $\Sigma_1$ statement, we get that $T_0$ forces that $\mathcal T$ is an extension of $T_0$, as it is a theorem of $\mathsf{ZFC}$ that if two normal trees are comparable, one is an extension of the other. Then the author claims, without proof, the following:

> there exist for each $s\in T_0$ an extension $T_0'$ of $T_0$ and some $t_s\in T_0'$ such that $$ s\text{ and } t_s\text{ are comparable and }T_0'\Vdash t_s\in\dot A.$$

But I have no idea why this is true, specially on the existence of the $t_s$, and I've been stuck on this for a while.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: This follows from $\dot A$ being a name for a maximal antichain. If $s\in T_0$ is a counterexample, you should be able to extend $\dot A$ by adding $s$ to it.

Comment: (By the way, Shelah proved the nice result that adding a Cohen real adds a Suslin tree.)

Comment: @AndresCaicedo sorry, but I can't follow you

Comment: (And Todorcevic has a very elegant proof of this.)

Comment: @CamiloArosemena Assume $s\in T_0$ is a counterexample. Go to a forcing extension by a generic $G'$ containing $T_0$. Let $\mathcal T'$ be the corresponding tree. In the extension, the interpretation $A'$ of $\dot A$ is a maximal antichain. Maximality implies that $s$ is related to $A'$ somehow. This should give you a $t_s\in A'$ comparable with $s$. Now argue that, by definition of $\mathcal T'$, you should have a $T_0''$ (in $G'$) with $t_s\in T_0''$ and $T_0''\le T_0$. Argue that a further extension $T_0'$ of $T_0''$ should be as desired.

Comment: @AndresCaicedo ok now I see :-), this is very clear using the argument of the generic containing $T_0$; I'm not used to this kind of argument.

Comment: @AndresCaicedo, thank you very much!

Comment: Glad I could be of help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(Turning the comments into an answer):

Let $s\in T_0$ be arbitrary. For me, the most natural way to argue is in terms of generics, so: Go to a forcing extension by a generic $G'$ containing $T_0$, and let $\mathcal T'=\bigcup G'$ be the corresponding tree. In $V[G']$, the interpretation $A'$ of $\dot A$ (that is, $A'=\dot A_G$) is a maximal antichain. Maximality implies that $s$ is comparable to some member of $\dot A$. Call this member $t_s$.

By definition of $\mathcal T'$, there must be a $T''_0\in G'$ such that $t_s\in T''_0$, and we may also assume that $T''_0\le T_0$. Since $t_s\in A'$, some $T'''_0\in G$ must force this, $T'''_0\Vdash t_s\in \dot A$. Let $T'_0$ be a common extension of $T'''_0$ and $T''_0$ (that we may pick in $G'$, if so desired). Then $T'_0\le T_0$ is as wanted.

Since $s\in T_0$ was arbitrary, we are done.

Comment: There is a technical detail I don't understand. The existence of $t_s$ is formally proved in $V[G']$. By absoluteness, you can obtain also in $V$ the existence of some $t_s$ which satisfies the statement quoted in the original post, **without** the part "and $T'_0 \Vdash t_s \in \dot{A}$". How can you make sure that the $t_s$ found in $V$ is also such that $V[G] \models t_s \in A'$? Maybe I miss something, but I think I need some absoluteness argument which is not completely trivial, since $V$ doesn't even know that $A'$ exists. Thanks

Comment: @aerdna91 I am just using the forcing theorem. (The "truth" property listed [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forcing_%28mathematics%29#Forcing).)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Unfortunately I think I couldn't make myself clear in last post. I'll try to explain my doubt again. Let $\phi(x)$ be the formula which says that "there exist for each $s\in x$ an extension $T_0'$ of $x$ and some $t_s\in T_0'$ such that $ s\text{ and } t_s\text{ are comparable}$. Let $\psi(x)$ be $\phi(x) \wedge t_s\in A$. You proved that, in $V[G]$, $\psi(T_0)$ is true. Now we could use the "truth" property to obtain a $p \in P$ such that $p \Vdash \psi(\dot{T_0})$, but that would be silly now, because we need to get the $t_s$ in $V$ [to be continued]

Comment: Of course by absoluteness we can show that $V \models \phi(T_0)$. Moreover, by the "truth" property, there is $p \in G'$ such that $p \Vdash t_s \in \dot{A}$. My question is: how can we make sure that, in $V$, the $t_s$ after the "$\Vdash$" is precisely the $t_s$ which is mentioned in $\phi(T_0)$ (in $V$)? It seems to me that we should argue by some kind of "pointwise" absoluteness, but I can't prove it formally.

Comment: @aerdna91 The tree $T_0'$ is in $V$, as are the trees $T_0''$ and $T_0'''$. The node $t_s$ is some specific node of $T_0''$.

Comment: Ok, I think I got it. The thing I was missing is that *every* witness $t_s$ for $\psi(T_0)^{V[G']}$ is a witness for $\phi(T_0)^V$ and **at the same time** is such that $(t_s \in A')^{V[G']}$ (this is what I meant by "pointwise"). The latter implies $p \Vdash t_s \in \dot{A}$ for some $p \in G'$ by the forcing theorem, and we are done.